# SSRS report won't follow parameter rules

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Having a bit of trouble here, and I'm sure I have to be overlooking something.

1st query:

```
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
    FROM Table1
```

2nd query (Will be used to create a drop-down parameter):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    Column1
    FROM Table1
    ORDER BY Column1
```

After putting this into SSRS, and creating a drop down parameter for the contents of Column1, I select the desired value and click View. However, instead of returning the specified value, it returns *all* values in Column1. I don't really want that.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used the parameter to filter your results.

There are two ways to do this - either use the parameter in your query and link it to your parameter on the **Parameters** tab of the **Dataset**.

You would add a where clause to your **1st Query** to filter the results. I will **ass**u**me** that you're using a **multi-value** parameter.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Column1 IN (@COLUMNS)
```

[image]

Or you could use the **FILTER** tab of the Dataset.

[image]

It's usually easier to do it in the **FILTER** tab but the report will usually run faster when using the **WHERE** clause. Filtering through the **FILTER** tab requires the query to bring back all results to the Report Server and then filter the results while using the **WHERE** clause lets SQL Server do the work of filtering and only returns the records needed.

Comment: All fixed. Thank you for your help!